# Pine script barssince confused

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine script and I will appreciate it very much any kind of help.  I have been using Python for my strategies but I am very interested in Pine script.  Based on the code below I would like to know if on the line below **"NH = valuewhen(high>k1[1],high,0)"** is k1[1] a series (list) or just one value.  What about
**barssince(high>k1[1])** below? Basically my question is: what is the difference of the value of k1[1] between **valuewhen(high>k1[1],high,0)** and **barssince(high>k1[1])**

```
boxp=input(5, "BOX LENGTH")

LL = lowest(low,boxp)
k1=highest(high,boxp)
k2=highest(high,boxp-1)
k3=highest(high,boxp-2)

NH =  valuewhen(high>k1[1],high,0)
box1 =k3<k2
TopBox = valuewhen(barssince(high>k1[1])==boxp-2 and box1, NH, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`highest()` returs `series float` so, `k1` is of `series` in all cases.

`[]` in `pinescript` is called [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) and is used to refer to the historical values of any variable of the series type.

So, `k[1]` refers to `k`'s previous value.

`valuewhen(high>k1[1],high,0)` will return the `high` price when `high > k[1]` was `true` the last time.

`barssince(high>k1[1])` will tell you how many bars ago this was.